# (Seemingly) undocumented transport mode in Here's Public Transit API

Tags: here-api

I'm trying out Here's [Public Transit API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit) and I'm getting the following response for my query:

```
{
  "Res":{
     "Connections":{
        "Connection":[
           {
              "duration":"PT50M",
              "transfers":1,
              "Dep":{...},
              "Arr":{...},
              "Sections":{
                 "Sec":[
                    {
                       "mode":20, //<-- THIS
                       "Dep":{
                          "time":"2019-02-25T09:29:00+01:00",
                          "Addr":{...},
                          "Transport":{
                             "mode":20
                          }
                       },
                       "Journey":{
                          "distance":268,
                          "duration":"PT04M",
                          "_guide":0
                       },
                       "Arr":{
                          "time":"2019-02-25T09:33:00+01:00",
                          "Stn":{...},
                          "AP":{...}
                       }
                    },
                    ...
                 ]
              }
           },
           ...
        ],
        "Operators":{...}
     }
  }
}
```

I'm able to infer that `mode: 20` means `walking`, but I can't find where is it documented to back my guess up.

The [transit modes documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/key-concepts-transit-codes.html) page lists modes up to only 14, even though exactly the same `mode: 20` pops up in their example on the mentioned [quick start page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit)

So, does anyone know where to look for what `mode: 20` and possibly other undocumented modes mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mode=20 means walking. Thank you for reporting this. The internal team is already on it. We shall update the documentation shortly.

Update: This issue has been addressed and you can find the information updated in our  [transit modes documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/key-concepts-transit-codes.html) page now.